# How to change the value of a field in its preprocess method?

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I am trying to figure out Drupal 8's `$variables` array ...

So I have a `MYTHEME.theme` file, complete with a working `MYTHEME_preprocess_field()` function. (I know it works because I use it for other fields that need customization.)

Right now I'm focusing on the title of an article displayed on the front page of my site. I can access it with the following code.

```php
if ($variables['field_name'] == 'title') {
    $title = $variables['element'][0]['#context']['value'];
    // ...
}
```

What I want to do is replace all instances of *®* (the registration mark) with `<sup>®</sup>`. However, setting this value in the array to something else does *not* change it on the site.

Is there something I'm missing? A few sources I found said to alter (or add) the *#markup* element in the array, but there's a dearth of information about this online.

How do I change the value of a field? This seems like it should be something basic and easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 front page is a view called **frontpage** if the view is not modified it should `show: "Content"` by default (instead of fields).  If so the following can be applied to change each node title

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  //for views that show: "Content" (not fields)
  if($variables["is_front"]){    
    $variables["label"][0]["#context"]["value"] .= " end of title";
  }
}
```